# Is there a way to protect/hide QNetworkAccessManager/QNetworkReply sensitive informations in Qt from a memory viewer?

Tags: c++, api, qt, qtnetwork

i'm trying to parse some data from a private GitHub repo using the Github API to connect and download the data as JSON.

Everything works fine but i have one big problem. Being a private repo, i don't want others to access sensitive data like the private repo key or the JSON content parse.

Here is my code:

**downloader.cpp**

```
#include "downloader.h"

downloader::downloader()
{
    connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
            this, &downloader::downloadFinished);
}

void downloader::doDownload(const QUrl &url, int mode)
{
    download_Mode = mode;
    const QString username = "test";
    const QString token = "1234567890"
    const QByteArray basic_authorization = QByteArray("Basic ") + (username + ":" + token).toUtf8().toBase64();

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setRawHeader(QByteArrayLiteral("Authorization"), basic_authorization);
    request.setUrl(url);

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);

    #if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors, this, &downloader::sslErrors);
    #endif

    loop.exec();
}

bool downloader::isHttpRedirect(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    return statusCode == 301 || statusCode == 302 || statusCode == 303
           || statusCode == 305 || statusCode == 307 || statusCode == 308;
}

void downloader::sslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &sslErrors)
{
#if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
    for (const QSslError &error : sslErrors)
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL error: %s\n", qPrintable(error.errorString()));
#else
    Q_UNUSED(sslErrors);
#endif
}

void downloader::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QUrl url = reply->url();
    if (reply->error()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Download of %s failed: %s\n",
                url.toEncoded().constData(),
                qPrintable(reply->errorString()));
    } else {
        if (isHttpRedirect(reply)) {
            fputs("Request was redirected.\n", stderr);
        } else {
            QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
            QByteArray e_Content = doc.object().value("content").toString().toUtf8();
            QByteArray d_Content = QByteArray::fromBase64(e_Content);
        }
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Problem is, when i run my program, if i use something like Process Hacker to inspect my process, i can see every sensitive data in plain text. It's like the username/token/json data/download link/header data never clears from memory.

Is there a way to clear the sensitive data from memory the moment download finished? Or, i can at least hide it somehow?

PS: I've tried encrypting both username/token but

```
request.setRawHeader(QByteArrayLiteral("Authorization"), basic_authorization);
```

is revealing my data in memory and never clears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parsing private information on client already looks like bad implementation. You can protect memory data by encrypting it in runtime, but you'll have to write it yourself. And also big warning: anything running on someone's PC can be reverse engineered. Even if you encrypt it, if someone desperately wants to see what's inside, he will be able to decrypt it or read before encryption.

Comment: I know that everything can be reverse engineered. I just want somehow to hide the text that is in plain sight. Also, why all data from Qnetwork resides in memory the whole time my app is running?

Comment: In C/C++, when memory data is released, data itself remains in it's previous state before it gets reassigned and something writes to it. For example, when you have "ABCD" in memory and it gets released, "ABCD" stays at same place, before someone allocates new memory and it overlaps with "ABCD". In this case, "ABCD" will get rewritten by for example "EFGH", or if you write "EFG", it will become "EFGD" (D from previous data).

Comment: based on your tips, i managed to "hide" some important string by rewriting the string values after they were used. The big problem remains with the response and headers from QNetwork. I have no clue how to rewrite/clear/zero the values of reply and .setRawHeader after the download is finished.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt and it's networking, but after some research I believe Qt doesn't give you direct access to data stored in QNetworkReply, so you cannot zero it out. I have read that it's possible to write own reply class and use it, but cannot say for sure. For headers, afaik it gives you QByteArray rawHeader, which has member function "fill".